# How can we generate terrain using simplex noise 2d with block position vectors

Tags: terrain, voxels

My problem might be special comparing to other questions related to terrain generation using simplex noise 2d.
Each chunk contains a table of 1-dimensional array which encompasses the position data( world positions ) and index( whether solid or air ) for every block within it. I separate the underground part( 3d noise portion ) and surface( 2d noise portion ) by doing this in the loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= width; x++){
  for(int y = 0; y <= height; y++){
   for(int z = 0; z <= depth; z++){
  /* Use 3d noise to Generate underground caverns and overhangs when z is smaller than 15 */
      if(z <= 15){
        if(USimplexNoise::SimplexNoise3D(x, y, z) > threshold){
          BlockIndex[].add(1);//solid
        }else{
          BlockIndex[].add(0);//air
        }
     }else{
  /* Switch to 2d noise and generate the surface when z is bigger than 15*/
  /* This is where I get confused */
        if(USimplexNoise::SimplexNoise2D(x, y) > threshold)
    }
   }
  }
}
```

In the surface generation part, I'm trying to assign a value for BlockIndex(Solid or air), but I have no idea about the way to do that when I have to determine whether a block should be solid or not using simplex 2d.

On what circumstance should the block be solid or air?

Pseudo-code would help a lot.

Comment: The noise only generates values, it's up to you how you interpret them

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by treating what simplexnoise2d(x, y) returns as the threshold( height value )
[image]